# How might ATC phrase an instruction to a pilot to maintain a certain speed and establish glide path?

Tags: air-traffic-control, radio-communications, terminology

What might an ATC say to instruct a pilot to maintain a certain speed and establish glide path?

My attempts (as someone who does not know much at all about how a plane is piloted) are:

- "Maintain XXX onto glide path"
- "Maintain XXX, report established on glide path"
- "Maintain XXX until intercepting glide path"

but I'm not sure about them at all, nor about any potential differences in nuance between them.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure one of the ATC folks will give a better answer based on standard phraseology, but #3 is closest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICAO standard phraseologies are  given in PANS-ATM Doc 44444 16th edition.
Refer the following standard Phraseologies given in the 12th Chapter.

Para 12.4.2.2

> d) CLEARED FOR (type of approach) APPROACH RUNWAY (number);
>
> k) MAINTAIN (altitude) UNTIL GLIDE PATH INTERCEPTION;

> e) REPORT ESTABLISHED ON LOCALIZER (or ON [GLS/RNP/MLS] [FINAL] APPROACH [COURSE]);

Para 12.4.1.6

> c) MAINTAIN (number) KILOMETRES PER HOUR (or KNOTS) [OR GREATER (or OR LESS)] [UNTIL (significant point)];

So these blocks of phraseologies can be adapted  to the above situation as

> CLEARED FOR (Type of Approach) Runway XX. MAINTAIN 190 KNOTS UNTIL GLIDE PATH INTERCEPTION.[REPORT ESTABLISHED]

Note that contents inside the square brackets in the sample phraseology are optional

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Is GLS/glideslope more commonly used than glide path? (Or do they not refer to the same thing?)

Comment: Sorry—did a search and realized GLS doesn't refer to glideslope. In that case, is "report established on glide path" not something that's said?

Comment: @Pearl6527 that's really depends on how the aircraft is carrying out the approach. Whether it is vectored on to the pilot interpreted final approach or carrying out a complete instrument approach etc. all the following are standard phraseologies depending upon the situation. "Report Established on Localizer", "Report established on ILS" , " Report establed on glide slope"